# I want to change css for widgetUserBox

Tags: html, r, shinydashboard

I want to change css for widgetUserBox, i want to move the box position with title name: Area600 as shown in fig:[image]

I want to get something like as shown in figure below
[image]

```
widgetUserBox(title="Area 600",type=2, collapsible = TRUE,color = "primary", width = 3,
                          tags$div(
                            class="box box-widget widget-user-2", style="left: 407px;bottom: 207px;"
                          )
```

but its not working. Kindly help me how to do css edit in shiny dashbaoard.

This is the change in css i need:

```
<div class="box box-widget widget-user-2" style="left: 407px;bottom: 207px;">
```

Comment: Have you ever tried bootstrap with his grid system ?

Comment: No, Can you give some example for bootstrap that can be used in a shiny dashboard.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/qz18xj5s/ have a look on this example, maybe it could help you.

Comment: That i understood, it is in HTML. I want to integrate CSS in the shiny dashboard. Did you have any example for CSS edit in the shiny dashboard?   Thanks in advance.